# How do I place JComponents on a Jframe background image?,

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I'm new here
I need help in placing components on a background image in Jframe using BorderLayout.
I tried adding the components to the label then the label to the frame but it hasn't worked so far

Here's my code:

```
package com.hosp;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BackgroundImage extends JFrame {

    BackgroundImage() {

        //get  image from package
        ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("backgroundimage.jpg"));

        //add image to Label
        JLabel imageLabel =new JLabel(img,JLabel.CENTER);

        //button on screen
        JButton btn =new JButton("Save");

        //
        add(imageLabel);
        imageLabel.add(btn,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

    public static void main(String []args) {

        BackgroundImage frame = new BackgroundImage ();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: please show us what have you done so far?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the relevant code as well as any errors or stack traces encountered.

Comment: @The Head Rush. There's been no error so far

Comment: I'd be astonished if there was no duplicate question among [this lot of Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjframe%5D+background+image).. General tips: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks but they were typo errors I forgot to edit

Comment: *"they were typo errors I forgot to edit"* -1 a great time to fix those errors is **when someone reminds you**. Please [edit] the question to fix it soon. I might then withdraw the down vote.

Comment: @AndrewThompson okay I will. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
public class backgroundImage extends        JFrame{
```

Class names should start with an upper case character

```
add(imageLabel);
imageLabel.add(btn,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
validate();
```

1. Unlike a JPanel, a JLabel isn't designed to be a "container" to hold other components so it doesn't have a default layout manager so you can't just add the component to it using a BorderLayout constraint.
2. There is not need for the validate() method. You would only use revalidate() and repaint() when you add a component to a panel AFTER the frame is visible.

So your code should look something like:

```
add(imageLabel);
imageLabel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
imageLabel.add(btn,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//validate();
```

Note this will only work if the components you add to the label are smaller than the size of the image, otherwise the component will be truncated to fit in the area of the label.

Check out [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a more flexible solution.

Comment: The button does show on the frame but its background is separate. Is there and way to place the button on the image?

Comment: The button does display on the label. It displays on the bottom of the label because you are using the BorderLayout.SOUTH. If you want the button somewhere else then use a different layout manager. For example use a FlowLayout on the label to see the difference. Or use a GridBagLayout to see the button in the center.